# GRASP: Aplicação do padrão Criador

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, projeto-de-software

Craig Larman (*Utilizando UML e Padrões*, pág. 352) propõe o seguinte problema de design:

> De quem é a responsabilidade de criar uma instância de Pagamento?

Pelo padrão GRASP Criador, os candidatos são a classe Registradora e a classe Venda.

No caso da classe Venda, ele justifica que ela é uma candidata por ser *"razoável pensar que ela usa Pagamento de maneira próxima"*.

Não consegui entender de onde ele tira isso. Pensei em duas possibilidades:

1. Depois de uma Venda completa vem um Pagamento.
2. Após um Pagamento será devolvido troco, e o cálculo desse troco vem da diferença entre o total da Venda e a quantia fornecida no Pagamento.

Existe mais alguma relação entre Venda e Pagamento que não estou conseguindo enxergar?

Comment: Chama ele aqui :D Você leu tudo ou só viu esse trecho? Ele não justifica? Joga fora :D

Comment: Li tudo. Será que vou ter que jogar? :x achei que estivesse me escapando alguma coisa óbvia, mas se mais gente não entendeu também, pelo menos eu não fico sendo o único. :)

Comment: Data de publicação?

Comment: O livro é de outubro de 2004.

Comment: Pra falar a verdade qualquer coisa que tenha UML no nome eu descarto, tudo é fundamentalmente errado, qualquer um que se dedique a escrever isso não tem muita credibilidade comigo. Pode ser que hoje a pessoa tenha mudado de ideia, mas o autor nessa época acreditava em algo que não agrega nada muito útil, traz problemas novos, e hoje há quem já enxergue isso.

Comment: Me parece um cara teórico que nunca fez um sistema real, mas só parece, não sei, pode ser só alguém que não consegue dar boas definições. Se tem a ver com venda, deveria haver um recebimento e não um pagamento. Normalmente o recebimento tem a ver com o financeiro não passa pela venda, mas sei lá, não conheço o contexto, ele pode ter razão. É o que eu falo, não tem livro que ensina modelar direito, nem a base abstrata, imagina quando precisa fazer algo concreto. Eu queria que alguém desse uma explicação coerente, mas acho que nem o autor consegue. É possível contatá-lo?Posta no SOen e chama ele

Comment: É um projeto de PDV para venda de produtos em um supermercado ou algo assim, está se referindo ao comprador pagar a compra com dinheiro no caixa. Não acho que o autor seja contatável, eu pelo menos já tentei falar com ele e não consegui.

Comment: Do ponto de vista da empresa que fez venda, ela recebe, porque se olha o ponto de vista do cliente, já está errado porque o sistema não pra ele, mas se fizer isto, o pagamento deve ser feito em uma compra. Ainda acho que é algo mal estruturado, e provavelmente nem há relação direta entre as coisas. Vai ver teve tanta gente reclamando do livro que ele sumiu :)

Comment: Ou isso, ou ele simplesmente não se dá ao trabalho de responder emails com perguntas aleatórias. :P mas dá um crédito para o livro, ele é bem recomendado pelo Martin Fowler e pelo Alistair Cockburn, se a recomendação deles vale para alguma coisa. :P

Comment: O Fowler tam altos e baixos, muito do que ele diz é marketagem, você nunca sabe quando é só isso. E não sei se ele não mudou de ideia ao longo do tempo, ele é um que já pregou coisas que não prega mais, mas fica quietinho. Eu não sei o que ele fez, não sei se fica bom. O outro você pode ler meu link no chat (no Linkedin) o que eu acho sobre Agile, então nem vou comentar.

Comment: Tem o Vlissides também. :) o caso é que se excluir as abordagens com UML não sobra nenhuma, todas as que achei usam (pós-97 pelo menos).

Comment: @Maniero Acho que não havia falado antes, mas a Venda provavelmente não é uma Compra porque o caso de uso é do ponto de vista do caixa (atendente).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Conceito representado por um objeto

Um projeto orientado a objetos terá classes e as instâncias correspondentes precisam ser criadas. O GRASP contribui com o padrão Criador com o propósito de orientar quem deveria criar uma instância de uma dada classe. Em tempo, trata-se de uma heurística, não é uma regra.

Um dos benefícios propalados da orientação a objeto é refletir com mais fidelidade o domínio em questão. Dito isto, observe sua afirmação, "Depois de uma venda completa vem um pagamento". Se no seu domínio em questão esta afirmação é verdadeira, então não faz sentido a classe Venda criar uma instância de Pagamento, como você sugere. E não há nenhum problema aqui.

Em outros cenários, um pagamento não ocorre após a venda, mas faz parte de uma venda. A venda, o conceito, a noção de venda é a transação efetivada entre cliente e fornecedor, na qual é comercializado um ou mais produtos, para a qual há um pedido, uma nota fiscal, um ou mais orçamentos, um pagamento, um parcelamento, ...  Tudo isto pode fazer parte de venda. Enfim, a questão aqui é como é definido venda no domínio em questão. Adicionalmente, observe que **não existe uma única definição correta**. De fato, em uma mesma instituição, um mesmo conceito pode ser representado de várias perspectivas distintas, conforme o uso que dele é feito no contexto em questão. Atualmente, podemos dizer que cada um destes contextos é um *bounded context* (Domain-Driven Design) e que será implementado por um micro-serviço.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, muito bem observado que Pagamento faz parte de Venda e não apenas "vem depois", só vou me isentar de avaliar a citação a microsserviço que é um tópico que não domino.

Comment: Observe que é uma questão "conceitual". Pode ser que em determinado cenário, o conceito de "pagamento" não faça parte de "venda", e isto pode acontecer em um mesmo sistema, neste caso, deveria ser em outro "micro-serviço", para ilustrar uma proposta de arquitetura de software amplamente comentada no momento. O *design* deve estar próximo do domínio, se o  domínio diz que faz parte, então faz, se diz o contrário, então não faz.